# Read .dat file exported from Dynamics ERP

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, erp

I have 6 GB .data file extracted from Microsoft Dynamics AX ERP system.
I'm unable to read the content as it gets distorted when I open it in Excel or text.

Help me out here, what is the best way to read it?

Is there any way of importing it as tabulation in R or another tool?

Comment: What error message have you encountered?

Answer (score 1):

Try using SQL Server Integration Services or some other ETL tool to transform it into CSV or import into a table in a database.

Comment: Could you please suggest some freeware or any tool.